# Display random files from the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
router.get("/alw", function(req, res){
    Product.find({"category": "alw"}, function(err, allProduct){
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.render("products/alw", {products: allProduct})
        }
    });
});
```

I want to display about 12-15 random products from the database without one occuring twice.
Please how do i go about it cus its confusing

Comment: `$group` and `$limit ` can do this, if you try them and you are stuck, give example data if you can

Comment: The above code displays all the products with that particular category. I want it to display just random products instead of everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
router.get("/alw", function(req, res){
    Product.aggregate([{$sample:{size:15}}], function(err, allProduct){
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.render("products/alw", {products: allProduct})
        }
    });
});
```

So I did a research and came up with the solution. So You can use `yourCollection.aggregate([{$sample:{size:numberOfObjectsToBeDisplayed}}]);` instead of `yourCollection.find()` because the later renders everything from the database while the former selects at random

Comment: That is the solution #1 that i wrote bellow but you didn't read the docs link that i posted. It says **WARNING $sample may output the same document more than once in its result set** that why i said take like 100 to be sure that you will take at least 15 unique.

Answer (score -2):

You can use $sample but from the documentation [See](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#behavior)
**WARNING $sample may output the same document more than once in its result set.**

Query

- sample like 100 to be sure
- group to keep unique only
- limit 15

```js
aggregate(
[ {"$sample" : {"size" : 100}},
  {"$group" : {
    "_id" : "$_id",
    "doc" : {"$first" : "$$ROOT"}
    }
  },
  {"$unwind" : {"path" : "$doc"}},
  {"$replaceRoot" : {"newRoot" : "$doc"}},
  {"$limit" : 15}
])
```